# Guid values stored in uppercase by EF Core 5 and SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I would like to use Guid's as the primary key in a SQLite database.
Everything works quite well so far, only the guid values ​​are saved in the table column with capital letters. Can the behavior be changed?
I need it in lower case.

**Update**

We need the Uuid in lower case because all Uuid in our applications that we have written with Dapper have this Uuid saved in lower case.

Since we now want to switch to EF Core, it would not be nice if all future Uuid were in capital letters because that would no longer be uniform.

I use EF Core and the code first approach.

Here some code that i use:

**The Contact Model**

```
public class Contact : ObservableObject
{
#region Properties

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

#endregion
}
```

**DbContext Overrides:**

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var stringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        BrowsableConnectionString = true,
        DataSource = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(App).Assembly.Location)}\\database.db3",
        Mode = SqliteOpenMode.ReadWriteCreate,
    };

    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(stringBuilder.ConnectionString);
    Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ConnectionString);
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new AddressConfig());
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactConfig());
}
```

**Entity Type Configuration:**

```
public class ContactConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Contact>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Contact> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(contact => contact.Id);
        builder.Property(contact => contact.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.HasMany(contact => contact.Addresses);
        builder.HasData(new Contact
            {
                Id        = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Addresses = new List<Address>(),
                FirstName = "Max",
                LastName  = "Mayer"
            });
    }
}
```

**Insert part of migration:**

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(
    table: "Contact",
    columns: new[] { "Id", "FirstName", "LastName" },
    values: new object[] { new Guid("eee4ecac-6250-4f29-a883-15cf32b28520"), "Max", "Mayer" });
```

**The result:**

[image]

Comment: A GUID is hexadecimal with values between 0-9 and A-F. So if you want a GUID then the answer is no. Why do you need it in lower case?

Comment: What is the type of the `Id` column in the database?  It looks like it is a GUID (in SQL Server, that's known as a _Unique Identifier_; don't know about SQLite).  A GUID has no letters or numbers, it is a 128-bit structure that is generally rendered in hex characters in a certain identifiable pattern.  Whether those hex characters include `[a-f]` or `[A-F]` has nothing to do with how anything is stored, it's purely a rendering issue.  This code: `new Guid("eee4ecac-6250-4f29-a883-15cf32b28520")` gives you exactly the same result as: `new Guid("EEE4ECAC-6250-4F29-A883-15CF32B28520")`.

Comment: If you are storing the GUID as a string in the database, take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_Guid_ToString_System_String_

Comment: If your code depends on the case of a GUID, you have massive problems.

Comment: Thanks for someone trying to help me.
@scottdavidwalker: We have written other applications where we use Dapper. At Dapper it is spelled correctly in lower case. According to the recommendation of https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.667/en under point 6.5.4.
Since we now want to work with EF Core in the future, it would be important that UUIDs are stored in lowercase letters as all IDs are stored in this format. 
Example: 'beb1b8a0-3ae0-40b9-a006-ef1758c48a53'

Comment: @Flydog57: The `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` commands create a TEXT Typed field which would be correct for SQLite. The Type in the Model is Guid for Id Property.

Comment: @ian-kemp: We need the Uuid in lower case because all Uuid in our applications that we have written with Dapper have this Uuid saved in lower case.

Since we now want to switch to EF Core, it would not be nice if all future Uuid were in capital letters because that would no longer be uniform.

Comment: So... You work with System.Guid in your code, but SQLite uses `TEXT` (i.e., strings, not real GUIDs).  You want the text to be lower-case when the System.Guid is converted to a string by the EF infrastructure.  So the question is how to coerce the EF infrastructure to use lowercase (I don't know the answer).  By the way, I followed your link to the ITU doc.  Sect 6.5 deals with hex representation. Sect 6.5.2 defines hex digits one of [0-9], [A-F] and [a-f] and hex octets as pairs of hex digits.  Their examples (informative) are in lower case, but both cases are normative.

Comment: @Flydog57: Yes, that's right. Both lower case and upper case are usually okay. But we wanted the UUIDs to be uniform in our databases. Still, thank you very much for your time. I have now found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the solution was `HasConversion(new GuidToStringConverter())`.
After I made the following changes, the UUID's were saved in lower case.

**New EntityTypeConfiguration**

```
public class ContactConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Contact>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Contact> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(contact => contact.Id);
        builder.Property(contact => contact.Id).HasConversion(new GuidToStringConverter());
        builder.HasMany(contact => contact.Addresses);
        builder.HasData(new Contact
                        {
                            Id        = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            Addresses = new List<Address>(),
                            FirstName = "Max",
                            LastName  = "Mayer"
                        });
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who took the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when calling:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

because the model's guid was in lower case but in db it was in upper case.
Setting COLLATE NOCASE solved my problem:

```
CREATE TABLE Contact (
    Id TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
);
```

Please have a look here:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19651
(comment from: bricelam commented on Jan 23, 2020).

Or if you want lower guid to be inserted so this trigger can help:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS TR_Style_To_Lower_GUID
AFTER INSERT ON TB_Style
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.Gid IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   UPDATE TB_Style SET Gid = (select lower(NEW.Gid)) WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

where TB_Style is the table and Gid is the PK.
Maybe this can help somebody else like me.