EF Core : error while inserting row in database with FK Constraint failure
I have an endpoint that instantiates a class then add tasks to this and finally saves in the database:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BusinessProposalController(IBusinessProposalRepository businessProposalRepository, IWorkTaskRepository workTaskRepository, IWorkTaskTypeRepository workTaskTypeRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork): ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateBusinessProposalRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // add request body validator
        var businessProposal = request.ToEntity();

        businessProposalRepository.Create(businessProposal);

        var workTasks = request.WorkTasks.Select(w => w.ToEntity(businessProposal.Id)).ToList();

        foreach (var workTask in workTasks)
        {
            var workTaskType = await workTaskTypeRepository.GetById(workTask.WorkTaskTypeId, cancellationToken);

            if (workTaskType == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = $"Work task type {workTask.WorkTaskTypeId} not found"});
            }
            
            workTaskRepository.Create(workTask);
        }

        await unitOfWork.Commit(cancellationToken);

        return Ok(new { id = businessProposal.Id});
    }
}

A request with this body:
{
  "name": "test",
  "customer": "test",
  "address": "test",
  "workTasks": [
    {
      "unitCost": 20.0,
      "quantity": 3,
      "workTaskTypeId": "d4a1f4fc-148a-4a91-ae8b-6c364fc9a558"
    }
  ]
}

produces this error when I remove the line that checks if worktaskType is already in the database:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ReportGenerator.Infra.Repositories.UnitOfWork.Commit(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\pedro.ferrari\Desktop\dev\work\report-generator\ReportGenerator\ReportGenerator.Infra\Repositories\UnitOfWork.cs:line 12
   at ReportGenerator.API.Controllers.BusinessProposalController.Create(CreateBusinessProposalRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\pedro.ferrari\Desktop\dev\work\report-generator\ReportGenerator\ReportGenerator.API\Controllers\BusinessProposalController.cs:line 37
   at lambda_method5(Closure, Object)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:5294
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:5294
Referer: http://localhost:5294/swagger/index.html
Content-Length: 205
sec-ch-ua: "Not)A;Brand";v="99", "Brave";v="127", "Chromium";v="127"
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-GPC: 1
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty

The thing is that I preload the database with all WorkTaskTypes that come from another source. I can access this values with my another endpoint that get all worktasktypes, like here:

and I have a lot of registers:

Debugging the code, I found out that I can't find the WorkTaskType by providing the Id while creating my entity in the ToEntity method:
public static class WorkTaskMapper
{
    public static WorkTask ToEntity(this CreateWorkTaskRequest request, Guid BusinessProposalId)
    {
        return new WorkTask
        {
            BusinessProposalId = BusinessProposalId,
            UnitCost = request.UnitCost,
            Quantity = request.Quantity,
            WorkTaskTypeId = request.WorkTaskTypeId
        };
    }
}

This doesn't point to any WorkTaskType and raise this FK constraint error.
Can someone help me? I'm kinda lost right now
EDIT 1
WorkTask entity:
public class WorkTask : BaseEntity
{
    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost => UnitCost * Quantity;

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Guid BusinessProposalId { get; set; }
    public BusinessProposal BusinessProposal { get; set; } = null!;

    public Guid WorkTaskTypeId { get; set; }
    public WorkTaskType WorkTaskType { get; set; } = null!;
}

WorkTaskType entity:
namespace ReportGenerator.Domain.Entities;

public class WorkTaskType: BaseEntity
{
    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }

    public string UnitType { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Category { get; set; } = null!;

    public int LaborId { get; set; } = 0;

    public ICollection<WorkTask> WorkTasks { get; set; } = [];
}

EDIT 2
Base repository class:
public class BaseRepository<T>(AppDbContext context) : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected readonly AppDbContext Context = context;

    public void Create(T entity)
    {
        entity.DateCreated = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        Context.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        entity.DateUpdated = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        Context.Update(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        entity.DateDeleted = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        Context.Remove(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetByIdAsQueryable(Guid id)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Id == id).AsQueryable();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAllAsQueryable()
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().ToList().AsQueryable();
    }

    public async Task<T?> GetById(Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await Context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> GetAll(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await Context.Set<T>().ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}


Others classes are just implementation of Base:
namespace ReportGenerator.Infra.Repositories;

public class WorkTaskRepository(AppDbContext context): BaseRepository<WorkTask>(context), IWorkTaskRepository
{
}



I have a configuration that loads on the AppDbContext class:
public class WorkTaskTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<WorkTaskType>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<WorkTaskType> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder
            .HasMany(e => e.WorkTasks)
            .WithOne(e => e.WorkTaskType)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.WorkTaskTypeId);
    }
}



That produces a ModelSnapshot like:
// <auto-generated />
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;
using ReportGenerator.Infra.Context;

#nullable disable

namespace ReportGenerator.Infra.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(AppDbContext))]
    partial class AppDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "8.0.7");

            modelBuilder.Entity("ReportGenerator.Domain.Entities.BusinessProposal", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Address")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Customer")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<DateTimeOffset>("DateCreated")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<DateTimeOffset?>("DateDeleted")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<DateTimeOffset?>("DateUpdated")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("BusinessProposals");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("ReportGenerator.Domain.Entities.WorkTask", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<Guid>("BusinessProposalId")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<DateTimeOffset>("DateCreated")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<DateTimeOffset?>("DateDeleted")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<DateTimeOffset?>("DateUpdated")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<int>("Quantity")
                        .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                    b.Property<decimal>("UnitCost")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<Guid>("WorkTaskTypeId")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("BusinessProposalId");

                    b.HasIndex("WorkTaskTypeId");

                    b.ToTable("WorkTasks");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("ReportGenerator.Domain.Entities.WorkTaskType", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Category")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<DateTimeOffset>("DateCreated")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<DateTimeOffset?>("DateDeleted")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<DateTimeOffset?>("DateUpdated")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Description")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<int>("LaborId")
                        .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                    b.Property<decimal>("UnitCost")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("UnitType")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("WorkTasksTypes");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("ReportGenerator.Domain.Entities.WorkTask", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("ReportGenerator.Domain.Entities.BusinessProposal", "BusinessProposal")
                        .WithMany("WorkTasks")
                        .HasForeignKey("BusinessProposalId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasOne("ReportGenerator.Domain.Entities.WorkTaskType", "WorkTaskType")
                        .WithMany("WorkTasks")
                        .HasForeignKey("WorkTaskTypeId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("BusinessProposal");

                    b.Navigation("WorkTaskType");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("ReportGenerator.Domain.Entities.BusinessProposal", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("WorkTasks");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("ReportGenerator.Domain.Entities.WorkTaskType", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("WorkTasks");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}


Thats all information i can provide to this case. Can someone help?



The first thing would be to check your WorkTask entity to be sure you aren't doing something like auto-initializing a WorkTaskType navigation property such as = new WorkTaskType(). Navigation properties will take precedence over FK properties when attempting to insert or update entities.

@StevePy just updated the question showing that im not doing this in this class

Can you add your Repository.Create method? I would suspect that your abstractions are hiding something because if it works simply by first loading the work task type using the same ID then something seems to be dependent on a related entity being tracked before an entity can be saved.  You could change the worktasktype property from an auto-property to a variable with a getter/setter then breakpoint the setter. I'd almost put money on something "setting" the nav property.

@StevePy just updated with repositories and modelsnapshot

I don't see anything obvious there, but a couple of things. #1, collection navigation property setters should be marked as protected rather than public. #2. For your repository GetAll() remove the .ToList(). This will be materializing and tracking every entity every time. You also do not need the .AsQueryable() in the other calls. Results of .Where() are already IQueryable<T>.  Process of elimination would be to bypass using the repository and go straight to the DbContext/DbSet and see if this changes behaviour.

The other thing that comes to mind may be the conversion between GUID and storage as a text string.  From discussions in the EF Core MySQL groups there has been some back & forth going on about EF storing lower-case strings for UUIDs.  What is the case of the FKs being stored in the database? If they are stored Upper Case then the join expression might fail, or something similar varying SQL between fetching by ID and joins. See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21659 and https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/1878

@StevePy lower case as shown in one of the prints. I took a look in those discussions and think that problem could be related to sqlite maybe. Im not planning to use it as my final DB so i will try SQL Server rn and see if something changes

When you imported the data the GUID was stored in lower case, however digging into this a bit more it looks like at least at one point EF Core would try to store GUIDs to text in Uppercase (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69209096/guid-values-stored-in-uppercase-by-ef-core-5-and-sqlite). If that is still the case SQLLite would likely fail the FK constraint. Capturing the INSERT statement would confirm that. WIth SQL Server it supports a UniqueIdentifier type so won't run into any issues with casting or case sensitivity.

@StevePy just changed to SQL Server, everything working fine.. find out that maybe was the case difference between EF search and SQLite storage
